# Will clearind data from download effect the downloader apps?

Tags: downloading, download-manager

!My device is samsung galaxy J5,  the download manager has currently 1.3 GB . I'm just curious will clearing the data from the download manger will effect apps wether it will delete the download applications? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIKev.png)

Comment: Your already installed applications will not be affected, instead only the download manager's data will be deleted. By this I mean, all the files, settings or databases ONLY found in the /data/data/com.android.providers.downloads and NOT already installed applications. Also whether you had downloaded them they are placed in Downloads folder of internal sd card or external sd card